# Why jQuery append doesn't push content down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a basic example of jQuery append with the button.

On first click button is correctly pushed down by new content.
On second click though the button stays in place and new content is pushing screen to the top, rather than appearing immediately after the first appended.

In other words, once you scroll to the button it always stays in place? Why it isn't getting pushed down by the appended content?

**UPDATE:** It seems like the issue is present in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```css
.appendTo {
  width: 600px;
}

#append {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.appended {
  width: 600px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.appended:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

.appended .child {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="appendTo">
</div>
<button id="append">Append</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#append').click(function() {
        $('.appendTo').append('<div class="appended"><div class="child">Child</div></div>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try it in Firefox...

Comment: @Kosh, seems top work fine. So is that a well-known Chrome behavior or bu or something? Is there any way to make Chrome work like Firefox?

Comment: Works fine in chrome for me.  Each new child is added to the bottom of the container under the previous ones, pushing the button further down the page.

Comment: @Phaelaxz I think that correct behavior would be seeing the top of the appended container, not the bottom and the button? Page basically shifts to keep button in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use different element and not the `button`, because Chrome wants to keep button in view maybe because of the focus or for some other reasons.

So changing `<button>` to e.g. `<a>` solves the the issue, not sure about accessibility though.